# jQuery mobile multiple html

Tags: html, jquery-mobile, cordova, multiple-insert

I am new for jQuery mobile. My project consist of 30 screen++. So I separate my screen to each single html. But now i facing one issues , because i need to include cordova.js to my project. So did i need to include cordova.js to all html ? It tat any better solution? It quite take time to me for include cordova.js to 30++ html.

Code

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Smart Realtor</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">  
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black"> 

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/smartrealtor-theme.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet"  href="css/custom.css"> 
    <link rel="stylesheet"  href="css/themes/default/jquery.mobile.structure-1.4.2.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet"  href="css/themes/default/jquery.mobile.icons-1.4.2.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet"  href="css/jqm-icon-pack-fa.css">

    <script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="js/globalsetting.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.mobile-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="cordova.js"></script>
    <script src="Calendar.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.mobile.fastButtons.js"></script>
</head>
```

Answer (score 0):

JQuery Mobile provides a JQuery mobile "page". These pages can be included in the same file but can also be loaded from separate files

If you use JQuery mobile pages you will only have to include dependencies on your main page rather than all of the sub pages. Please read the [Page Documentation](http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.4.2/pages/)

Comment: Hi I nt really understand. Let say my app consist of index.html, default1.html, default2.html . I only need to include cordova.js to index.html?

Comment: Yes, provided you follow the page documentation.